# default host for facebook webdriver when not local computer

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am trying to get "**facebook/php-webdrive**r" working on a **dedicate server**. the  example given at the github page mentions that the default host is:

```
http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
```

Do I need to change it or it still has to remain as default for example I change it to somthing like:

```
http://www.example.com
```

If I have to change it, change it to what?

This is the complete line of code which is pasted from the github page of facebookwebdriver

```
$driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, DesiredCapabilities::firefox());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver#getting-started it looks like a Selenium Server is required to be running before you can use the `php-webdriver`.

The URL `http://localhost:4444/wd/hub` is actually referring to the selenium server, and NOT to any website. You can replace `localhost` by any machine name (or) ip and `port` by the actual port (if its not the default `4444`), but the rest of the URL has to remain the same.

You test case will hit the above URL, for browser instantiation. Once browser has been instantiated, you can launch any website using the `driver.get()` command.